# fitrm with Nan values by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, anova, data-fitting

I have a table of data feeding to fitrm to model the data an feed it to ranova but I have a nan value than cause an error. is t5here any way to overcome this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should clean your data first. MATLAB has built-in function `isfinite` to check for Inf and nan values. For example:

```
x = [1;2;3;nan];
x(isfinite(x))
ans =

     1
     2
     3
```

Comment: You mean to remove the rows with nan values?

Comment: Yes, you can use isfinite function to check for nan values in your rows and remove the rows found.

Comment: but this is not favored while we are performing statistics that means we should neglect whole information in one row because of one missing elemant

Comment: You can checkout mixed models. I am not an expert in this field.  https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/advantages-of-repeated-measures-anova-as-a-mixed-model/ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215197/dealing-with-missing-data-in-repeated-measures-anova?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa